# Binding datatable with to JSON array from autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete, datatable

I am using an autocomplete field to get data from a server and display that in a datatable:

$("#firstname").autocomplete({

```
    source: function (request, response) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "http://myhost.com/webservices/test3.cfm",
             data: request,
             success: function (data) {
                    $('#results').dataTable({
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bLengthChange": true,
                        "bFilter": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        "bRetrieve" : true,
                        "aaData": data , 
                        "aoColumns": [
                            { "sTitle": "Name", "sName": "name" },
                            { "sTitle": "Title", "sName": "title" },
                            { "sTitle": "Organization", "sName": "organization" },
                            { "sTitle": "Email", "sName": "email" },
                            { "sTitle": "Status", "sName": "status" }
                        ]
                    });
             }
         });
    }
```

The data return from the ajax call is: 
[["Steven, Grek", "President", "Sands Corp.", "steven@yahoo.com", "1"],["Steven, Grek", "Associate", "Alliance Ltd.", "steven@yahoo.com", "1"],["Steven, Grek", "President", "Forest Products Association", "steven@yahoo.com", "1"]]

I get the following errors:

- DataTables warning (table id = 'results'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0
- DataTables warning (table id = 'results'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 9
- Showing 1 to 10 of 2,147 entries

If I replace "aaData": data 
with the response from in the data:
 
"aaData": [["Steven, Grek", "President", "Sands Corp.", "steven@yahoo.com", "1"],["Steven, Grek", "Associate", "Alliance Ltd.", "steven@yahoo.com", "1"],["Steven, Grek", "President", "Forest Products Association", "steven@yahoo.com", "1"]]

it works.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of a co-worker:
The typeof data coming from my ajax call is a string.

```
$("#firstname").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
     $.ajax({
         url: "http://myhost.com/webservices/test3.cfm",
         data: request,
         success: function (data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);      <---- typeof data is a string
            $('#results').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "bRetrieve" : true,
                "aaData": obj,                 <---- Use the parsed json object instead
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sTitle": "Name", "sName": "name" },
                    { "sTitle": "Title", "sName": "title" },
                    { "sTitle": "Organization", "sName": "organization" },
                    { "sTitle": "Email", "sName": "email" },
                    { "sTitle": "Status", "sName": "status" }
                ]
            });
         }
     });
   },
```

});